# Difference between Euclidean space and $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

What is the difference between Euclidean space and $\mathbb R^3$?

I have found in some books that they are the same, but in other references like Wikipedia, it says that a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ is a point in the Euclidean space, and the difference of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is a vector in the Euclidean space.

Comment: Its not an algebraic geometry question. It is a projective/affine geometry question.

Comment: @TroyWoo : I've changed the tags.

Comment: Roughly speaking, in Euclidean space, you don't add two points; with the push of a vector, you move from one point to another. But if you choose a particular point as the "origin", the Euclidean space looks like a vector space: a vector starting from the origin corresponds uniquely to its end-point.

Comment: And Euclidean space also has a metric, whereas $\mathbb R^3$ may have a natural metric only on each line separately.

Answer (score 5):

Some books will tell you that they are the same, and some will speak of Euclidean spaces in higher dimensions.  It's a matter of convention.

However, the space $\mathbb R^3$, when not assigned an inner product, is only a vector space, so that one cannot speak of angles and distances as one would in Euclidean space.  And the space $\mathbb R^3$ has an origin, whereas in Euclidean geometry one does not single out a particular point to play a special role different from the roles of all other points.

Answer (score 0):

A concise mathematical term to describe the relationship between the Euclidean space $X = \mathbb E^n$ and the real vector space $V = \mathbb R^n$ is to say that $X$ is a [principal homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space) (or ''torsor'') for $V$.
This is a way of saying that they are definitely **not** the same objects, but they very much **are** related to each other.

In particular:

- The objects $\mathbb E^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$ are exactly the same as  sets of elements -- they both correspond bijectively to $n$-tuples of real numbers.

However (as mentioned by OP),

- in the vector space $\mathbb R^n$ we are allowed to add any two vectors (using the ''tip to tail'' visualization), 
  whereas  in Euclidean space $\mathbb E^n$
  there is no natural way to describe the process of ''adding''  two points.
  Instead, given two points $P,Q$ in $\mathbb E^n$ we can naturally define their *difference* $\vec{v} = P-Q$, which is a vector  in $ \mathbb R^n$.
  This vector tells us how to get from point $Q$ to $P$.
- in $\mathbb R^n$ there is a special ''zero vector'' $\vec{0} = (0,\ldots,0)$ which satisfies the additive property $\vec{0} + \vec{v} = \vec{v}$ for any $\vec{v}\in \mathbb R^n$, 
  while in $\mathbb E^n$ there is no point that is somehow more special that the other ones -- i.e. the space is ''homogeneous'' meaning it looks the same around every point.

In the general context, we say that $X$ is a torsor for a group $G$ if $X$ is a copy of $G$ which ''forgets'' where the identity element is.
This means the underlying sets are bijectively the same, and gives the group $G$ a natural action on the set $X$ in the same way that $\mathbb R^n$ acts on $\mathbb E^n$
(i.e. the action is free and transitive).

This [blog post](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html) of John Baez discusses a few natural examples of torsors motivated by physics, and gives definitions in more detail if you are interested.